# How can I back up my iCloud Drive?

Tags: osx, backup, macos

I have a Mac and an external hard drive that I want to use to **automatically** and **periodically** back up my entire iCloud Drive.

I don't know if it's possible to change the iCloud default location to point to the hard drive, but anyway macOS doesn't keep all the files locally. This is an old Mac that would be dedicated to this, the external hard drive would always be connected to it so I don't mind pointing the iCloud folder to another path or anything like that.

Another important requirement is that I need to back up two different iCloud accounts.

It would be ok to only back up Photos if it's not possible to back up the drive.

I'm looking for a software or even just a script that could do this. I'm willing to pay but it would be nice if it was free. I don't want other software that would back up things on the cloud though, it needs to be in my local hard drive.